# Protecting work on client's web host

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I am taking on a freelance job making modifications to a client's already existing website/Wordpress theme. What is the best way to work on the client's current web host without putting myself at risk that the client might lock me out of the server and have all the code I've done before paying? Is it possible to create a child theme that points to files on my own server?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I didn't know if there was another way to go about it. The client is actually using WPEngine as a host which has an option to work in a sandbox environment. Maybe I will just explain that I prefer to work on my own servers for speed reasons and need to make the complete copy to my own servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get a copy of the files and then work locally using VVV, MAMP or whatever your tool of choice is. WP_Engine allows for git deploys so you could work locally and use git for version control and back up as well as deploy the changes as needed.